# Which test do I use to compare two groups for significance in a 2x2 design?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

I have a 2x2 design.

"Aorta disease(AD) - Aorta healthy(AH)" on the X-axis 
"Pulmonary disease(PD) - Pulmonary healthy(PH)" on the Y-axis.
**So: A=ADPD, B=AHPD, C=ADPH, D=AHPH**

I want to compare the results of **A (ADPD)** and **D (AHPH)** for significance. Which test do I use for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you just want to compare those two groups?

Answer (score 1):

The question is not clear about what you are measuring.

If you are just counting how many cases are in each combination of aorta and pulmonary conditions, then you can [use odds ratio as a measure of association and a chi-squared independence test to assess if this association is significant](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Should_I_use_Chi_square_or_odds_ratio).

However, if you are measuring a quantitative outcome from your patients, then you can use [2 way ANOVA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-way_analysis_of_variance) to assess if that quantitative outcome depends on pulmonary and aorta conditions.

Your question seems to address the first answer, although the wording "2x2 design" is usually related to the later.